Specify asymetrical breaks in `scale_fill_stepsn()`
I want to add a stepped gradient for the fill aesthetic, with specific colors for specific intervals.
For instance, I'd like red between 0 and 15, blue between 15 and 18, etc.
Here is the closest I've (painfully) come to my goal:
library(tidyverse)
val_breaks = c(0, 15, 18, 20, 25)
col_breaks = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "purple")

#4 intervals, 4 colors
cut(mtcars$qsec, breaks=val_breaks) %>% levels()
#> [1] "(0,15]"  "(15,18]" "(18,20]" "(20,25]"

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = qsec)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_stepsn(
    colors=col_breaks,
    limits=c(0,25),
    breaks=val_breaks,
    values=scales::rescale(val_breaks)
  )


Created on 2024-12-08 with reprex v2.1.1
As you can see, the colors are not really respected and mix with each other.
Is there a way?

I don't see what the problem is.  Did you intend for the color to be based on mpg? If so use color = mpg?

@MichaelDewar I'm confused about your comment, the problem is explained in the last sentence. The actual colors are not red, blue, yellow, purple, but something like magenta, purple, yellow, pink.

Okay I understand now.  Thanks

You can achieve your desired result by passing the midpoints of the intervals to the values= argument and by setting the from= argument of rescale according to the limits= used for the scale:
library(tidyverse)

val_breaks <- c(0, 15, 18, 20, 25)
col_breaks <- c("red", "blue", "yellow", "purple")

midpoints <- val_breaks[-1] - diff(val_breaks) / 2

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = qsec)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_stepsn(
    colors = col_breaks,
    limits = c(0, 25),
    breaks = val_breaks,
    values = scales::rescale(
      midpoints,
      from = c(0, 25)
    )
  )


Explanation
The reason is that a binned scale is still a continuous scale and the color palette is still a color gradient but the color assigned to all points in a bin is based on the midpoint of the interval or bin.
With scales::rescale(val_breaks) you specified that the colors apply to the edges of the bins. But as the color for each bin is based on the midpoint you end up with a mix of the colors at the bins edges, i.e.
pal <- scales::pal_gradient_n(
  col_breaks,
  scales::rescale(val_breaks),
  "Lab"
)

pal(scales::rescale(midpoints, from = range(val_breaks))) |>
  scales::show_col()


Hence, to fix the issue we have to make sure that the colors apply to the midpoints:
pal2 <- scales::pal_gradient_n(
  col_breaks,
  scales::rescale(midpoints, from = range(val_breaks)),
  "Lab"
)

pal2(scales::rescale(midpoints, from = range(val_breaks))) |>
  scales::show_col()


